# 'Unhide' Is Commonly Used, Why Doesn't It Appear on Any Vocabulary?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, colloquial-language

I noticed that the word 'unhide' it's widely used, though a quick research [on multiple vocabularies](https://www.onelook.com/?w=unhide) didn't bring anything relevant up.

This word is extremely common in IT when talking about files, for example.

Is the use of 'unhide' formally considered a colloquialism, slang or a mistake?

Please correct me if I am just looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Unhide - Webster's 1913 Dictionary - v. t. 1. To bring out from concealment; to discover. Found by typing 'unhide meaning' into Google.

Comment: The prefix **un** can be attached to virtually any verb, noun, adjective, or adverb. The editors of a dictionary must decide which of them are common enough to warrant the effort to include them—and, in the case of printed versions, the cost of the paper. Imagine the awkwardness of a dictionary in which the section beginning with **un** is 1/3 the length of the total.

Comment: Even if a word is in very common use, dictionaries might well omit it if its derivation and meaning are transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unhide means to remove the "hidden" setting on some element in a graphical user interface.  It d[idn't really have much use before 1980](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unhide&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunhide%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cunhide%3B%2Cc0), and still isn't used outside of computer terminology.  It's not slang or a colloquialism, but it is jargon.

In general use "reveal" is the word to use.

Why is there a difference?  Probably because, before GUI there was little reason for a person to "hide" something except to hide it *from someone else*. But when you "hide" a column in Excel, you aren't trying to keep it secret from another person, you are trying to simplfy the appearance of your spreadsheet. So the sense of "hide" when used in a GUI is different from "hide" in non-computer language.

(prior to excel, most use of the word are quoting Milton, who write "unhide-bound corpse" meaning a body not bounded by skin)

Comment: Upvoted, but I think you mean 'simplify'!